# Select Distinct XML attributes which starts with some text by Xslt

Tags: xslt

I have one Xml which has multiple attributes and some attributes starts with some common text.

```
<root name="Measures" >
    <Member name="MAF94">
        <Member name="MAF95">
            <Member name="MAM1" />
            <Member name="MAM2" />
        </Member>
        <Member name="MAF96">
            <Member name="MAF97">
                <Member name="MAM254" />
                <Member name="MAF98">
                    <Member name="MAM73" />
                    <Member name="MAM74" />
                    <Member name="MAF99">
                        <Member name="MAM11" />
                        <Member name="MAM10" />
                    </Member>
                    <Member name="MAF100">
                        <Member name="MAM18" />
                        <Member name="MAM15" />
                    </Member>
                </Member>
            </Member>
        </Member>
        <Member name="MAF352">
            <Member name="MAM1814" />
            <Member name="MAM1815" />
        </Member>
    </Member>
</root>
```

How to get distinct attributes which matches with some text. 
In the above example, I want to select only attributes which starts with "MAM" letters.

Thanks

Comment: Please show your expected output document.

Comment: '<root name="Measures" >
     <Member name="MAM1" />
     <Member name="MAM2" />
     <Member name="MAM254" />
     <Member name="MAM73" />
     <Member name="MAM74" />
     <Member name="MAM11" />
     <Member name="MAM10" />
     <Member name="MAM18" />
     <Member name="MAM15" />
     <Member name="MAM1814" />
     <Member name="MAM1815" />
    </root>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about ...

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
<xsl:output encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="@*|text()|comment()|processing-instruction()|*" />

<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//Member[substring(@name,0,3)='MAM']" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Member">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```